# Print Ansible-format variable from inside a loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I would like to print, in a configuration file, the following line:

```
{{ variable.method }}
```

This will be interpreted by a third-party software and will do whatsoever.

I am using Ansible. 
Printing the line with the following code, in a simple `template` block, is working well:

```
{{ '{{' }} variable.method {{ '}}' }}
```

However, when I want to loop on my `template` code to generate more files, using `with_items`, I can not print what I want anymore.

```
- name: Debug Print my variable
  with_items:
    - { name: "someObject", prop: "{{ '{{' }} variable.method {{ '}}' }}" }
  debug:  msg="{{ item.prop }}"
```

I receive the following:

```
FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: {u'name': u'someObject', u'prop': u'{{ variable.method }}'}: 'variable.method' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'my_file.yml': line 1, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: \"Debug Print my variable\"\n  ^ here\n"}
```

It looks like **Ansible** is working in a different environment/context and is trying to actually execute this piece of code. 
How can I *escape this context* and actually print what I wish?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to fix your loop to something like this if you would like to use `template` within a loop:

```
- name: Debug Print my variable
  template: ........ {{ item }}  #you write your template here
  with_items: 
    - { name: "someObject", prop: "{{ '{{' }} variable.method {{ '}}' }}" }
  debug: ............
```